# Adding Check Box for the Rows to select the specific grid row to export to excel

Tags: excel, extjs, grid, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export the grid to excel, which is working fine for the below,
 Now What i Want to implement is the Checkbox for the grid when I select the header checkbox all the grid cloumns should be select for exporting for excel,
 else only the selected rows for the export along with the column headers, How will I be able to achieve this. Below is the Code Snippet.

```js
var Base64 = (function () {
    // Private property
    var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    // Private method for UTF-8 encoding

    function utf8Encode(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        var utftext = "";
        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            } else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
        }
        return utftext;
    }

    // Public method for encoding
    return {
        encode: (typeof btoa == 'function') ? function (input) {
            return btoa(utf8Encode(input));
        } : function (input) {
            var output = "";
            var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
            var i = 0;
            input = utf8Encode(input);
            while (i < input.length) {
                chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
                enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
                enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
                enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
                enc4 = chr3 & 63;
                if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                    enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                    enc4 = 64;
                }
                output = output +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
                    keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
            }
            return output;
        }
    };
})();

Ext.define('MyApp.overrides.view.Grid', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',
    requires: 'Ext.form.action.StandardSubmit',

    /*
        Kick off process
    */

    downloadExcelXml: function (includeHidden, title) {

        if (!title) title = this.title;

        var vExportContent = this.getExcelXml(includeHidden, title);

        /*
          dynamically create and anchor tag to force download with suggested filename
          note: download attribute is Google Chrome specific
        */

        if (Ext.isChrome) {
            var gridEl = this.getEl();
            var location = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + Base64.encode(vExportContent);

            var el = Ext.DomHelper.append(gridEl, {
                tag: "a",
                download: title + "-" + Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d Hi') + '.xls',
                href: location
            });

            el.click();

            Ext.fly(el).destroy();

        } else {

            var form = this.down('form#uploadForm');
            if (form) {
                form.destroy();
            }
            form = this.add({
                xtype: 'form',
                itemId: 'uploadForm',
                hidden: true,
                standardSubmit: true,
                url: 'http://webapps.figleaf.com/dataservices/Excel.cfc?method=echo&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-excel&filename=' + escape(title + ".xls"),
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                    name: 'data',
                    value: vExportContent
                }]
            });

            form.getForm().submit();

        }
    },

    /*

        Welcome to XML Hell
        See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066(v=office.10).aspx
        for more details

    */
    getExcelXml: function (includeHidden, title) {

        var theTitle = title || this.title;

        var worksheet = this.createWorksheet(includeHidden, theTitle);
        if (this.columnManager.columns) {
            var totalWidth = this.columnManager.columns.length;
        } else {
            var totalWidth = this.columns.length;
        }

        return ''.concat(
            '<?xml version="1.0"?>',
            '<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">',
            '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Title>' + theTitle + '</Title></DocumentProperties>',
            '<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><AllowPNG/></OfficeDocumentSettings>',
            '<ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">',
            '<WindowHeight>' + worksheet.height + '</WindowHeight>',
            '<WindowWidth>' + worksheet.width + '</WindowWidth>',
            '<ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>',
            '<ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>',
            '</ExcelWorkbook>',

            '<Styles>',

            '<Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">',
            '<Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>',
            '<Borders/>',
            '<Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000"/>',
            '<Interior/>',
            '<NumberFormat/>',
            '<Protection/>',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="title">',
            '<Borders />',
            '<Font ss:Bold="1" ss:Size="18" />',
            '<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1" />',
            '<NumberFormat ss:Format="@" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="headercell">',
            '<Font ss:Bold="1" ss:Size="10" />',
            '<Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:WrapText="1" />',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#A3C9F1" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="even">',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#CCFFFF" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="evendate" ss:Parent="even">',
            '<NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy-mm-dd" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="evenint" ss:Parent="even">',
            '<Numberformat ss:Format="0" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="evenfloat" ss:Parent="even">',
            '<Numberformat ss:Format="0.00" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="odd">',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#CCCCFF" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="groupSeparator">',
            '<Interior ss:Color="#D3D3D3" ss:Pattern="Solid" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="odddate" ss:Parent="odd">',
            '<NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy-mm-dd" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="oddint" ss:Parent="odd">',
            '<NumberFormat Format="0" />',
            '</Style>',

            '<Style ss:ID="oddfloat" ss:Parent="odd">',
            '<NumberFormat Format="0.00" />',
            '</Style>',

            '</Styles>',
            worksheet.xml,
            '</Workbook>'
        );
    },

    /*

        Support function to return field info from store based on fieldname

    */

    getModelField: function (fieldName) {

        var fields = this.store.model.getFields();
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].name === fieldName) {
                return fields[i];
            }
        }
    },

    /*

        Convert store into Excel Worksheet

    */
    generateEmptyGroupRow: function (dataIndex, value, cellTypes, includeHidden) {

        var cm = this.columnManager.columns;
        var colCount = cm.length;
        var rowTpl = '<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0"><Cell ss:StyleID="groupSeparator" ss:MergeAcross="{0}"><Data ss:Type="String"><html:b>{1}</html:b></Data></Cell></Row>';
        var visibleCols = 0;

        // rowXml += '<Cell ss:StyleID="groupSeparator">'

        for (var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
            if (cm[j].xtype != 'actioncolumn' && (cm[j].dataIndex != '') && (includeHidden || !cm[j].hidden)) {
                // rowXml += '<Cell ss:StyleID="groupSeparator"/>';
                visibleCols++;
            }
        }

        // rowXml += "</Row>";

        return Ext.String.format(rowTpl, visibleCols - 1, Ext.String.htmlEncode(value));
    },

    createWorksheet: function (includeHidden, theTitle) {
        // Calculate cell data types and extra class names which affect formatting
        var cellType = [];
        var cellTypeClass = [];
        console.log(this);
        if (this.columnManager.columns) {
            var cm = this.columnManager.columns;
        } else {
            var cm = this.columns;
        }
        console.log(cm);
        var colCount = cm.length;
        var totalWidthInPixels = 0;
        var colXml = '';
        var headerXml = '';
        var visibleColumnCountReduction = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < cm.length; i++) {
            if (cm[i].xtype != 'actioncolumn' && (cm[i].dataIndex != '') && (includeHidden || !cm[i].hidden)) {
                var w = cm[i].getEl().getWidth();
                totalWidthInPixels += w;

                if (cm[i].text === "") {
                    cellType.push("None");
                    cellTypeClass.push("");
                    ++visibleColumnCountReduction;
                } else {
                    colXml += '<Column ss:AutoFitWidth="1" ss:Width="' + w + '" />';
                    headerXml += '<Cell ss:StyleID="headercell">' +
                        '<Data ss:Type="String">' + cm[i].text.replace("<br>", " ") + '</Data>' +
                        '<NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles"></NamedCell></Cell>';

                    var fld = this.getStore().getModel().getFields(cm[i].dataIndex);
                    console.log('printing fldddd'+this.getModelField(cm[i].dataIndex));

                    switch (fld.$className) {

                    case "Ext.data.field.Integer":
                        console.log('Here Im typing 11111' + fld.$className);
                        cellType.push("Number");
                        cellTypeClass.push("int");
                        break;
                    case "Ext.data.field.Number":
                        console.log('Here Im typing 2222' + fld.$className);
                        cellType.push("Number");
                        cellTypeClass.push("float");
                        break;
                    case "Ext.data.field.Boolean":
                        console.log('Here Im typing 33333' + fld.$className);
                        cellType.push("String");
                        cellTypeClass.push("");
                        break;
                    case "Ext.data.field.Date":
                        console.log('Here Im typing 4444' + fld.$className);
                        cellType.push("DateTime");
                        cellTypeClass.push("date");
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log('Here Im typing 555555555' + fld.$className);
                        cellType.push("String");
                        cellTypeClass.push("");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var visibleColumnCount = cellType.length - visibleColumnCountReduction;

        var result = {
            height: 9000,
            width: Math.floor(totalWidthInPixels * 30) + 50
        };

        // Generate worksheet header details.

        // determine number of rows
        var numGridRows = this.store.getCount() + 2;
        if ((this.store.groupField && !Ext.isEmpty(this.store.groupField)) || (this.store.groupers && this.store.groupers.items.length > 0)) {
            numGridRows = numGridRows + this.store.getGroups().length;
        }

        // create header for worksheet
        var t = ''.concat(
            '<Worksheet ss:Name="' + theTitle + '">',

            '<Names>',
            '<NamedRange ss:Name="Print_Titles" ss:RefersTo="=\'' + theTitle + '\'!R1:R2">',
            '</NamedRange></Names>',

            '<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="' + (visibleColumnCount + 2),
            '" ss:ExpandedRowCount="' + numGridRows + '" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultColumnWidth="65" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">',
            colXml,
            '<Row ss:Height="38">',
            '<Cell ss:MergeAcross="' + (visibleColumnCount - 1) + '" ss:StyleID="title">',
            '<Data ss:Type="String" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">',
            '<html:b>' + theTitle + '</html:b></Data><NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Titles">',
            '</NamedCell></Cell>',
            '</Row>',
            '<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">',
            headerXml +
            '</Row>'
        );

        // Generate the data rows from the data in the Store
        var groupVal = "";
        var groupField = "";
        if (this.store.groupers && this.store.groupers.keys.length > 0) {
            groupField = this.store.groupers.keys[0];
        } else if (this.store.groupField != '') {
            groupField = this.store.groupField;
        }

        for (var i = 0, it = this.store.data.items, l = it.length; i < l; i++) {

            if (!Ext.isEmpty(groupField)) {
                if (groupVal != this.store.getAt(i).get(groupField)) {
                    groupVal = this.store.getAt(i).get(groupField);
                    t += this.generateEmptyGroupRow(groupField, groupVal, cellType, includeHidden);
                }
            }
            t += '<Row>';
            var cellClass = (i & 1) ? 'odd' : 'even';
            r = it[i].data;
            var k = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
                if (cm[j].xtype != 'actioncolumn' && (cm[j].dataIndex != '') && (includeHidden || !cm[j].hidden)) {
                    var v = r[cm[j].dataIndex];
                    if (cellType[k] !== "None") {
                        t += '<Cell ss:StyleID="' + cellClass + cellTypeClass[k] + '"><Data ss:Type="' + cellType[k] + '">';
                        if (cellType[k] == 'DateTime') {
                            t += Ext.Date.format(v, 'Y-m-d');
                        } else if (!Ext.isEmpty(v)) {
                            t += Ext.String.htmlEncode(v);
                        }
                        t += '</Data></Cell>';
                    }
                    k++;
                }
            }
            t += '</Row>';
        }

        result.xml = t.concat(
            '</Table>',
            '<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">',
            '<PageLayoutZoom>0</PageLayoutZoom>',
            '<Selected/>',
            '<Panes>',
            '<Pane>',
            '<Number>3</Number>',
            '<ActiveRow>2</ActiveRow>',
            '</Pane>',
            '</Panes>',
            '<ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>',
            '<ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>',
            '</WorksheetOptions>',
            '</Worksheet>'
        );
        return result;
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'arshadsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone','date','actualstart'],
            data: {
                'items': [{
                    'name': 'Arshad11111',
                    "email": "kahdkha@abc.com",
                    "phone": "6488646486",
                    "date":"2016-03-23",
                    "actualstart":"18:00:00"
                }, {
                    'name': 'Aesadasdasd',
                    "email": "asdsadasd@sdsc.com",
                    "phone": "6488646486",
                    "date":"2016-03-23",
                    "actualstart":"18:00:00"
                }, {
                    'name': 'gadjandna',
                    "email": "asdjf@ndfnsdos.com",
                    "phone": "6488646486",
                    "date":"2016-03-23",
                    "actualstart":"18:00:00"

                }, {
                    'name': 'asdasdasd',
                    "email": "asdasd@dfsdf.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1254",
                    "date": "2016-03-23",
                    "actualstart":"18:00:00"
                }, ]
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            },
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Arshads',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('arshadsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            },{
                text: 'Date',
                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                dataIndex: 'date',
                format: 'Y-m-d',
                flex: 1

            },
            {
            text: 'Start Time',
            dataIndex: 'actualstart',
            flex: 1
            }],

            height: 300,
            width: 400,
            dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'Download to Excel',
                        handler: function (b, e) {
                            b.up('grid').downloadExcelXml();
                        }
                    }]
                }

            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sm8)

Comment: selModel: {
                selType: 'checkboxmodel'
            },  [fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tcf)

Comment: and you can select record by using this

Comment: var grid = yourgrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

Comment: i dont have much experience but i hope it something useful  :)

Comment: It's not downloading the excel part there.. @SalmanhassanOkZ

Comment: i know you can just get idea from it just like you said you want a specific row to select here the selection thing i told ya :)

Comment: Yeah this idea i had , I don't know how to implement in the fiddle just to get the selected rows,

Comment: let me try with my own fiddle

Comment: That'd be Great :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont have much experience but i am sharing what i have
for Checkbox Selection you have to add in your grid config this

> [Here is a simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tcf)

```js
{
  selType: 'checkboxmodel'
},
```

and for records or one record selection you can use this method

```js
handler: function(b, e) {
  var str = b.up('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
  if (str && str.length) {
    window.open('../xxxxx/xx/xx?str=' + str);
    //your print file url goes here
  } else {
    Ext.Msg.show({
      title: "Print Error",
      msg: "you need to select a row before print."
    });
  }
}
```

AND if you want to print one specific row of grid by id you should use something like this

```js
var items = new Array();
if (str.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    items[i] = str[i].get('id');
  }
}
return items;
```

Hope this will help you a little!